# Rails Admin 'Record Not Found' during edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

Trying to edit a record in Rails_Admin and for various fields I'm getting a 'Record Not Found' message.

[image]

It looks like it gets committed in the log, but that's not the case, it's more like a 'rollback' action... which isn't logged.

Is there something else that I need to add to the rails_admin config file to allow additional fields?  My config file is the standard one from running `rails g rails_admin:install` with a few model exemptions added.

It seems the fields that I'm having an issue updating through rails_admin were added through migrations **after** installing rails_admin (Not sure if that matters or not).

Comment: Make sure to add the new attributes to the `permit_params` array of allowed attributes in that model's active admin config.

Comment: @infused so add it in the model?  In this case, my model is `Company`... so add it to `models/company.rb` ?

Comment: The `admin/company.rb` has its own allowed attributes that need to be updated.

Comment: From what I can tell, Rails_admin doesn't follow the same hierarchy as ActiveAdmin.  So I don't have a `config/initializers/rails_admin/XXXX.rb` file for my model.

Comment: To further support my assumption... https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Mass-assignments-protection